# Why is the saturation magnetisation of a ferromagnet increased by lowering temperature?

Tags: ferromagnetism

- I am referring to the B-H hysteresis curve of a ferromagnet under a cycled H field
- I understand thermal disorder increases as higher temperatures, resulting in a transition to paramagnetism above the Curie temperature.
- However, I expect at saturation that the system energy is lowest by having all dipoles aligned with the H field, regardless of the temperature.
- With this understanding, I expect that the saturation magnetization would be a material property independent of the temperature.